# What is the preferred method of command line domain name lookup (DNS)?

Tags: network, command-line, bonjour, dns

What command line command do I use to lookup a domain address?

When looking at the man pages for nslookup and dig I can see a section saying that these utilities do not use the Mac OS methods of finding names.

So, what command should I be running?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`nslookup`, `host`, and `dig` are perfectly good DNS query tools in OS X, but they all query DNS directly rather than going through OS X's internal resolution system. As a result, they don't check the /etc/hosts file, or resolve Bonjour/mDNS names (those ending in .local). The standard (quick 'n dirty) way to test resolution is to use `ping`, since it'll resolve the address you give it through the usual system before attempting to ping it. If you want something intended for the purpose, use `dscacheutil` instead:

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name www.apple.com
name: e3191.c.akamaiedge.net
alias: www.apple.com www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net www.apple.com.edgekey.net 
ip_address: 184.24.141.15

$ ping www.apple.com
PING e3191.c.akamaiedge.net (184.24.141.15): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 184.24.141.15: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=57.258 ms
^C
--- e3191.c.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 57.258/57.258/57.258/0.000 ms
```

Comment: Kudos. I've filed a Radar that the manpages should be clearer on this: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5038477976535040

Comment: One issue with using dscacheutil for lookups is that if it cannot resolve a hostname it doesn't exit with a non-zero return code like host does.

Comment: To overcome the lack of useful return codes I've created a most basic shell script to supplement the standard 'host' command.

`#!/usr/bin/env bash
STAT=1
LOOKUPRESULT="$(dscacheutil -q host -a name "$1")"
if [ -z "$LOOKUPRESULT" ] ; then
 exit "$STAT"
else
 echo "$LOOKUPRESULT"
 STAT=0
 exit "$STAT"
fi`

Answer (score 4):

Either command works fine.  Just because it's not using OS X's methods doesn't mean that it doesn't work.  If you want to use "OS X methods" may I recommend Network Utility?

[image]

This may still call whois and just display it in the window.

Comment: I guess this doesn't work for `.local` addresses, does it?

Comment: No, this won't work for .local addresses. This uses a public whois server, and .local addresses won't be posted there.