# "device not configured" error when attempting to reach specific websites

Tags: error, internet

A few months ago I posted the question [getting "out of memory" error when trying to load specific websites (am not out of RAM)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73263/getting-out-of-memory-error-when-trying-to-load-specific-websites-am-not-out) regarding bizarre `could not allocate memory` errors when I attempted to load certain specific websites (and was absolutely positively not out of memory), even though my internet connection was otherwise fine. That problem spontaneously vanished for a while, but now I'm experiencing the same behavior with a number of other sites and a different error message.

Attempting to load any of these sites in a browser gives me a generic `could not connect` message. When I try to ping them, I get this message:

```
ping: sendto: Device not configured
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

Things that haven't helped:

- Using a different network
- Using a wired instead of wireless network
- Logging in as a different user
- Rebooting (it actually did help on one occasion, but the problem reappeared a few minutes later)
- Requesting different pages on the site or using variants on the URL (e.g., with or without `www`)
- Using the site's IP address instead of the name

I haven't been able to determine whether the same problem occurs when I use a VPN, because one of the sites that will no longer load is my VPN :P

The error occurs before the computer has even tried to load the site, but after it receives the IP address.

**update**: partial list of non-working sites (all of these are publicly available):

- http://users.humboldt.edu
- http://vpn.ucsf.edu
- http://cpx.sagepub.com/
- http://www.helioscalendar.com/
- http://www.ajcn.org

Comment: Can you disclose any of the non working sites so we can try to recreate the problem.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thanks for the suggestion; I've added a list.

Comment: Great, so the San Francisco opens fine at log in screen, in Firefox. The Helioscalender also works. It does have a application/x-shockwave-flash in it that might cause your problem.

Comment: And they all work in Chrome!

Comment: It doesn't appear to even be trying to load the site. Also note that I get these anomalous error messages when I use ping, so I don't think it has to do with the content of their web pages. I've also verified that these sites respond to pings normally using a different computer.