# Various random website cannot be reached (cannot allocate memory)

Tags: network, macos, internet

With process of elimination and testing the problems on 2 different Macs, 4 different networks, and many different browsers, I have isolated the cause of my network issue to be the actual Mac.

Certain sites, even though they are up, are completely unreachable by one of my Mac. Visiting on Chrome says:

```
Error code: ERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

Safari says:

```
The operation couldn't be completed. Cannot allocate memory
```

`ping` says:

```
ping: sendto: Cannot allocate memory
```

I have no idea what to do next. I check my Network setting and no proxies are on. Is there any way to reset my network settings? Or any commands to provide more information to allow more diagnostic?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered restarting the computer to determine if you have a program with a memory leak or if indeed there is a problem with the system and apps after a fresh start?

Comment: Actually just time will eventually fix the problem. But it will happen again for random other sites like facebook or even google. I'm not even sure if it's a virus or some kind rerouting my network traffic or something.

Comment: Also may be a dupe of this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73263/getting-out-of-memory-error-when-trying-to-load-specific-websites-am-not-out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What fixes it for me for wireless connection is this:

1. Go to network preferences
2. Open the connection data
3. Open "Advanced..." properties
4. Go to "TCP/IP" tab
5. Set "Configure IPv4" to off (remember the previous setting)
6. Click "OK" and then Apply
7. Wait for the connection to be reset
8. Go back to TCP/IP and re-enable IPv4 to the previous setting
9. Click "OK" and then "Apply" again

After the connection restores, the memory errors are gone. Still no idea why it happens or why this fixes it, but seems to work for me and is much faster than rebooting.

Comment: This worked to restore access to a particular website that I was not able to access. It was very frustrating, but these steps solved it.